# What are deployment best practices for projects in Python?

Tags: python, deployment, jupyter-notebook, web-deployment

Using jupyter, I have created a small product which takes an excel file as input and produces another excel. What is preferred deployment strategy on premise?

Web-App sounds like a reasonable start, however, I do not want to create a risk of losing sensitive data. Docker deployment seems like a overkill. I want to package all the dependencies to ease the clients process.

Comment: "There are some restriction on installing dependencies in the computer of the person that will run the script" - what are the restrictions at the other end?

Comment: I don't think they will allow me to install python, virtual enviroments or each of the packages that the script depends on; which is only numpy and pandas.